# How to produce a confusion matrix from cross validation?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, lda

I'm new to R and machine learning and I'm using data with 2 classes. I'm trying to do cross validationl, but when I try to make a confusion matrix of the model I get an error that all arguments must have the same length. I can't understand why what I've input doesn't have the same length. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
library(MASS)
xCV = x[sample(nrow(x)),]

folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(xCV)),breaks=10,labels=FALSE)

for(i in 1:10){

  testIndexes = which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
  testData = xCV[testIndexes, ]
  trainData = xCV[-testIndexes, ]

}
ldamodel = lda(class ~ ., trainData)
lda.predCV = predict(model)

conf.LDA.CV=table(trainData$class, lda.predCV$class)
print(conf.LDA.CV)
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your code is you are not doing the modeling and the prediction inside the loop, you just generate one `testIndexes` for `i == 10` since you overwrite all others.

The following code will be done on iris data:

```
library(MASS)
data(iris)
```

generate the folds:

```
set.seed(1)
folds <- sample(1:10, size = nrow(irisCV), replace = T) #5 fold CV
table(folds)
#output
folds
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
10 12 17 16 21 13 17 20 12 12
```

or if you would like equal sized folds:

```
set.seed(1)
folds <- sample(rep(1:10, length.out = nrow(irisCV)), size = nrow(irisCV), replace = F)
table(folds)
#output
folds
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
```

run the model by making the model on 9 folds and predicting on the hold out:

```
CV_lda <- lapply(1:10, function(x){ 
  model <- lda(Species ~ ., iris[folds != x, ])
  preds <- predict(model,  iris[folds == x,], type="response")$class
  return(data.frame(preds, real = iris$Species[folds == x]))
})
```

this produces a list of hold out predictions, to combine it to a data frame:

```
CV_lda <- do.call(rbind, CV_lda)
```

produce a confusion matrix:

```
library(caret)

confusionMatrix(CV_lda$preds, CV_lda$real)
#output
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

            Reference
Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         50          0         0
  versicolor      0         48         1
  virginica       0          2        49

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.98            
                 95% CI : (0.9427, 0.9959)
    No Information Rate : 0.3333          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       

                  Kappa : 0.97            
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: setosa Class: versicolor Class: virginica
Sensitivity                 1.0000            0.9600           0.9800
Specificity                 1.0000            0.9900           0.9800
Pos Pred Value              1.0000            0.9796           0.9608
Neg Pred Value              1.0000            0.9802           0.9899
Prevalence                  0.3333            0.3333           0.3333
Detection Rate              0.3333            0.3200           0.3267
Detection Prevalence        0.3333            0.3267           0.3400
Balanced Accuracy           1.0000            0.9750           0.9800
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the seeds dataset from `hglm.data`

```
library(MASS)
data(seeds, package = "hglm.data")


seedsCV = seeds[sample(nrow(seeds)),]
folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(seedsCV)),breaks=10,labels=FALSE)

lda.predCV <- integer(length(folds))

for(i in 1:10){

  testIndexes = which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
  testData = seedsCV[testIndexes, ]
  trainData = seedsCV[-testIndexes, ]

  ldamodel = lda(extract ~ ., trainData)

  lda.predCV[testIndexes] <- predict(ldamodel, testData)$class

}

lda.predCV <- factor(lda.predCV, labels = c("Bean", "Cucumber"))
```

Print out the confusion matrix and accuracy:

```
conf <- table(pred=lda.predCV, actual=seedsCV$extract)
accuracy <- sum(diag(conf))/sum(conf)

> conf
          actual
pred       Bean Cucumber
  Bean       10        0
  Cucumber    0       11


> accuracy
[1] 1
```